# Need to Fetch datetime input from one model and post it as a day in another model API using Django

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, dayofweek

Need to fetch the Date entered in the below model Timesheet and display it as Day in a new model as a api

#Model
class Timesheet(models.Model):

```
Date=models.DateField()

Hours=models.TimeField(null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.id
```

Need help on creating a report table day wise(example: if we enter a date as 28.01.2022, it needs to display as Friday in the new model).

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the day. You can use this method to assign day in another model also as your necessity.

```
from datetime import date
import calendar
def __str__(self):
    return calendar.day_name[self.Date.weekday()]
```

Comment: #model 1
class Timesheet(models.Model):
Date=models.DateField()

Hours=models.TimeField(null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.id

#model 2
class Day(models.Model):
    days = models.ForeignKey(Timesheet, related_name='days', on_delete=CASCADE, default=None)
    
days = models.ManyToManyField(Timesheet)

 def __str__(self):
        return Timesheet.Date[self.days]

I runned the above code but it doesnt fetch the day of the date, it is showing an error as "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "App_day" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "App_day"."id" FROM "App_day""

Comment: can you please look into my code and give us a solution for the same